# Is there an upper bound for expectation of product of two measurable function on a random variable?

Tags: probability, inequality

I wonder if there is an useful upper bound for $\mathbb{E}_{x\sim p(x)}[f(x)g(x)]$ in the following form:
$$
\mathbb{E}_{x\sim p(x)}[f(x)g(x)] \leq \mathbb{E}_{x\sim p(x)}[f(x)]\times xxxxxx
$$

The RHS of the inequality is required to be a product.

Thanks~

Comment: You can always estimate the missing term in the RHS by $\max_x |g(x)|$. I doubt that you can do any better as the special case $f = g$ has to included and you can't estimate the second moment of a r.v. by its first moment.

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to know that $\mathrm{Cov}(f,g)\le 0$ then you get the upper bound $\mathrm{E}(fg)\le\mathrm{E}(f)\mathrm{E}(g)$. [Similarly, if $\mathrm{Cov}(f,g)\ge 0$ then you get the lower bound $\mathrm{E}(fg)\ge\mathrm{E}(f)\mathrm{E}(g)$.] This relies on the identity:

\begin{equation}
\mathrm{Cov}(f,g)=\mathrm{E}(fg)-\mathrm{E}(f)\mathrm{E}(g)
\end{equation}

As Hans Engler alludes to in a comment above, if $f\ge 0$, then $fg\le f\max_x|g(x)|$ and therefore

\begin{equation}
\mathrm{E}(fg)\le\mathrm{E}(f)\times\max_x|g(x)|
\end{equation}

However in general, as far as I know, there is very little else you can do to bound $\mathrm{E}(fg)/\mathrm{E}(f)$.